# type convert of long to date time or date in moor database - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor, moor

I'm receiving long value from Api and I'am trying to create type convertor to convert long values to data time or date. How can I do it?

Comment: in which formate u r getting data?

Comment: long, and because we don't have long in Dart, I guess converter is between int and date time

Comment: i did't get what u want have u want to change that long value in intger?

Comment: no, I'm receiving the long value, I want to add convertor for it and save it as a DateTime in moor

Comment: Saying that you get an integer value isn't useful without knowing what it represents.  Is it [the number of seconds since the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)?  The number of milliseconds?  If so, you can use [`DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/DateTime/DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch.html).  If it's a number of seconds, you'll need to multiply by 1000 first.  If it's measured from some other reference date, you will need to adjust it, but nobody can tell you what to do without more details.